# 2D Poisson equation and Bessel Functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, integral-transforms, bessel-functions

If I were to solve a inhomogeneous 2D Laplace's equation (in polar coordinates), of the form:

$$\nabla^2 f= J_2(r)$$

How would I use the Hankel or the Mellin transform to find a solution? I couldn't find any references on the subject. Thanks!

Comment: An introductory reference is R.V. Churchill *Operational Mathematics*. There's a chapter on Hankel transforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you think it does make sense though to use Hankel Transform, or should I expand in Fourier as usual and express $J_2$ that way? Would this work as well?

Comment: Erdeyli has a collection of transforms of all kinds. You might learn just enough to check if what you want is there. That's what I would have to do. Erdeyli has quite a bit about Mellin transforms as well in Vol I. And Vol II has Hankel transforms. Look into the Bateman Manuscript Project to find the compiled tables. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman_Manuscript_Project . The last reference listed on the page is a link to the publicly available scanned manuscripts.